# Is there a way to get a list of app and run it programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I need to get the list of camera apps installed on my phone. (example : Camera, Camera 360, Instagram, etc.. ) and run it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this framework:

https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp

You can then launch any of the detected apps by using the scheme for whichever app you want to launch.

Comment: There's only 11000+ URL schemes in that github library. There are over one million apps in the app store. That list is pretty useless.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that some of the apps installed on my phone can't be seen on iHasApp. 

so, is what am I trying to do is possible?

Comment: You have to decide which apps you absolutely have to support.  Most of the major ones are in there.  If the app has a large audience, and supports a custom scheme, then yes - you'll probably find it.  Would you really want to support every possible app?

Comment: well, that's a good point. I might just make my on list for now. Thanks!